# Set of real whose image under any continuous function is a perfectly meager nullset

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Sierpinski showed in *Hypothèse du Continu* that there exist a set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with the cardinality of the continuum whose image under any continuous function is a nullset. (Proposition $C_3$ on page 49. It is a consequence of Theorem 2 on page 41 and - assuming CH - the existence of a Lusin set).

He also showed that there exist a set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with the cardinality of the continuum whose image under any continuous function is perfectly meager. (Propostion $C_{30}$ on page 86. It is a consequence of Theorem 1 on page 85 and - assuming CH - the existence of a Sierpinski set).

Does there exist a set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with the cardinality of the continuum whose image under any continuous function is a perfectly meager nullset ?

Comment: Sure, I've added references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misquoting Sierpinski. Although one can construct an uncountable set of reals which is both perfectly meager and universally null in ZFC alone, the existence of a size continuum perfectly meager or universally null set is independent of ZFC.